# How to upgrade Ubuntu and keep Steam game data?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, home-directory, steam, user-data

I wanted to know how I could keep my data from Steam if I were to upgrade my Ubuntu version in the future. I have a very great amount of experience of Linux and I have installed Ubuntu before. I know how to partition a hard drive. I was think that if I make a /home partition that Steam and its data would be saved here. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steam keeps all its data in your home folder (specifically, `.local/share/Steam/`), and uses the `SteamApps` directory within it for downloaded content (unless you configured it to use a different location. Since upgrading usually leaves your home folder untouched, Steam data should also be left untouched.

You can also make a separate partition for `/home`, but it would simpler to make Steam use a different location (on some other partition).

Comment: So, for example if I upgraded Ubuntu 13 to 14 all my Steam data would not be deleted if I made a /home partition.

Comment: @TylerSantos if you're upgrading, it shouldn't be deleted at all (even if you don't have a separate partition). A separate partition will help if you reinstall or make a fresh install of Ubuntu.

Comment: @TylerSantos I usually make Steam use a different location (by adding a library), and the location is on another partition.

Comment: +1, if you *upgrade* then Steam data will not be overwritten at all, but if you *reinstall* you would then want to consider partitioning.